# Why is "are developers stakeholders" closed?

Tags: support, status-completed, closed-questions

I came across [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/are-developers-a-stakeholder-in-a-system) that was closed because it's "not a real question" when cleaning up [software-engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-engineering). Why was it closed? So far, the answers are pretty poor. This question is easily answerable, but doesn't have any good answers yet. It's a clearly answerable question, as this post answers it. Due to the low quality of answers, it should either be reopened so that a high-quality, correct answer that cites reputable sources can be provided or deleted to prevent the wrong answers from surfacing, especially since this linked question is #2 on my Google search for "are developers stakeholders".

Citing Karl Wieger's Software Requirements:

> **stakeholder** A person, group, or organization that is actively involved in a project, is affected by its outcome, or can influence its outcome.

Citing Ian Sommverville's Software Engineering 8:

> The term *stakeholder* is used to refer to any person or group who will be affected by the system, directly or indirectly. Stakeholders include end-users who interact with the system and everyone else in an organisation that may be affected by its installation. Other system stakeholders may be engineers who are developing or maintaining related systems, business managers, domain experts, and trade union representatives.

Roger S. Pressman's Software Engineering: A Practitioner's Approach (6th Edition) defines five groups or stakeholders: senior managers who define business issues, project/technical managers who organize and control the practitioners, the practitioners who engineer the system, customers who specify the requirements for the software, and end-users who will interact with the delivered system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I recall correctly, I closed it because it was pretty vague and received comments on it from other people suggesting it was "not a real question".

I'm assuming the bulk of your question here is what you'd post as an answer, so it looks like you have a good answer in mind. I'm reopening the question so you can post it.